# Local structs and character arrays memory is not cleaned after function return

Tags: c, arrays, char, initialization

I have declaration of couple of char arrays and structs in a function that process string message. This function is called periodically and I noticed that variables have same data as on previous function call.

```
void handle_incoming_message(void)
{
    // All further variables keep previous value 
    message_fields msg_params;
    message_data msg;

    char base_response[16];
    char payload_response[14];
    char tx_msg[50];
    char response_buf[128];

    if(is_valid_msg(&msg, &msg_params) == 1u) // Check if there is message in queue and Checksum is ok
    {
        /* Get all message fields into struct */
        get_msg_fields(&msg_params, &msg); 
     ........

    }
}
```

And that leads to an error, so when I process the message and forward it the message is corrupted,
having some extra data from previous message (See picture). First terminal is original message, 2d is redirected.

[image]

I have also checked in debug mode and variables show the same value on next call, before they were somehow used.(see picture). Data of response_buf, when function was called 2d time.

[image]

Why does this happens? Shouldn't local variables be cleaned up after function return? What is the correct way to handle such case?

Update: Message_fields struct added.

```
typedef struct message_fields{
    uint8_t sender_id;
    uint32_t payload_fields[NOF_PAYLOAD_FIELDS];
    uint8_t receiver_id;
    uint16_t msg_id;
    uint8_t payload_length;
    char payload_type;
    char payload[128];
    uint8_t checksum;
    uint8_t peripheral_id;
} message_fields;
```

Comment: Do your messages get terminated with '\0'?

Comment: You will need to provide a [mcve] to get help on this.  Without knowing how the rest of the code is calling this function (and the ones it calls) it is not possible to provide accurate help.

Comment: Sounds like you aren't initializing some array properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local variables declared within a function that are not *explicitly* initialized can have any values whatsoever - and that would include the values 'left over' from any previous call to the function. Exactly how your particular compiler and build system implement the memory for such variables is not specified by the standard.

To prevent problems derived from the use of such uninitialized data, add explicit initializers to your code. The following sets all 'local' data to zeros (you haven't given us the definitions for `message_fields` and `message_data`, so I'm giving 'possible' initializers for them):

```c
void handle_incoming_message(void)
{
    // All further variables keep previous value 
    message_fields msg_params = { 0, };
    message_data msg = { 0, };

    char base_response[16] = { 0, };
    char payload_response[14] = { 0, };
    char tx_msg[50] = { 0, };
    char response_buf[128] = { 0, };

    if (is_valid_msg(&msg, &msg_params) == 1u) // Check if there is message in queue and Checksum is ok
    {
        /* Get all message fields into struct */
        get_msg_fields(&msg_params, &msg);
        ........

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation, that works out. Added the definition of message_fields:

Any way to initialize it fast to 0, such as in case of arrays:
char base_response[16] = { 0 }; ?

Comment: @Fen The initializer syntax for the arrays also works for your `struct` variables; see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct_initialization) ... *"All members that are not initialized explicitly are initialized implicitly the same way as objects that have static storage duration."*

Comment: Note to OP: This code shows initializing things to zero, but that is just one example. You should initialize as appropriate for your uses. Initializing all objects to zero is not the correct solution for code that has a bug of using uninitialized objects. A correct solution is to initialize all objects to correct initial values. There is no reason to think zero is correct for any particular purpose, except that it is common for many purposes, and habitually initializing things to zero can work to conceal bugs instead of remedying them.

Answer (score 2):

If local variables are not explicitly initialized, their values are **indeterminate**.  You can't depend on them having any particular value, and in fact you can invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) if you attempt to read them.  Typically, implementations will not attempt to clear them when they are created.  That's one of the things that makes C fast.

Your code should explicitly initialize any variables you were reading uninitialized with appropriate default values so that it will behave deterministically.